# Windows update DirectX fix for Win7 available?

Tags: windows-update

Recently Microsoft added a bug fix for DirectX games which has this message included in their fixlist:

> Addresses issue where, in certain hardware configurations, the frame
>   rates of DirectX Games were unintentionally limited to a factor of the
>   display's vertical synchronization.

source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4074588/windows-10-update-kb4074588

I wonder if this exists on Windows 7 as I seem to have the same issue there, I can't find it, maybe a kind soul out here know how to?

Comment: The fix in question only exists on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

It’s really impossible to say.

I find it interesting that it doesn’t *specifically* say it’s a fix for DirectX, but states “specific hardware configurations.” This leads me to believe this is a Windows 10 operating system specific fix.

However in my opinion, if it was a DirectX bug, it is not likely going to be an issue on Windows 7. Windows 7 only supported DirectX 11, which has been out for a *very* long time. I would believe most of the bugs would have been ironed out while it was under support.

Sadly, if this actually is a DirectX bug that was present in v11, you are out of luck. Windows 7 has been out of support for years and Microsoft is not making any patches for it.

Comment: Windows 7 is about to be out of support but not yet, security patches are still being issued.

Comment: @MichaelBay On January 13, 2015 Microsoft stopped mainstream support of Windows 7.  Only security updates will be available till January 14, 2020.

Comment: But im playing an old game though that uses DX9 and that was an issue on Win10 and was fixed with this patch, but on Win7 its the same problem, fps is dropped whereas 2 years ago with the same game it never was that low with the same settings